# Analytical geometry text

Tags: reference-request

Could someone give me a reference to a rigorous introduction (So I understand what's going on, that doesn't just give out formulas without explanation,etc.)to analytical geometry text ?? Keep in mind that I only have knowledge of high school math!(equations of second degree,etc.)

Thank you again !

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.6521

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will love this book: http://ksu.edu.sa/sites/py/ar/mpy/departments/math/learnResources/ResourceCenter/Documents/euclidegeometry.pdf
a rigorous introduction.
knowledge of high school math is more than enough.

Comment: The link is broken, could you please write the name of the book?